# Remove textarea while preserving formatting

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea where users can edit some text. On click of an element I need to to remove textarea from around text, while preserving formatting, like line breaks etc. I need to do it with jQuery, because I cannot refresh the page.

```
$(document).on("click", ".close", function() {
    var formattedText= $(this).prev("textarea").text();
    $(this).prepend().text(formattedText);
});

<textarea>
   Formatted text here.
   And here...
</textarea>
<button class="close">Remove textarea</button>
```

Comment: so you need to  delete the outline of text area but not the text??

Comment: Why do you need to do this exactly? From what you've said so far, any reason you can't just remove the border with CSS?

Comment: I don't need it to be editable. It's not just the border. I was thinking of using .unwrap() but it didn't work: $(this).prev("textarea").unwrap();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use `val()` for `textarea` to get the inputted text.

First you get the text value, then you replace the `textarea` with a div with the inputted text.

```
$(document).on("click", ".close", function() {
  var formattedText= $("textarea").val();
  $('textarea').replaceWith('<div>'+ formattedText +'</div>');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4aoLvbr9/1/)

**EDIT**

You can preserve line breaks by adding `white-space:pre;` to your CSS code.

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4aoLvbr9/2/)

Comment: You're correct with using `val()`, but just using a div won't preserve line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If line breaks are the only bit of formatting, then something like this would work:

```
var $textarea = $(this).prev('textarea');
var text = $textarea.val();
// format text by replacing new lines with '<br>'
var formattedText = text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');

// replace text area with div that has formatted text
var $div = $('<div>').text(formattedText);
$textarea.replaceWith($div);
```

If you don't want to remove the textarea altogether, you can hide it and place the div before/after it.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to mess with changing the CSS of the textarea (other than just hiding it), you can have an empty `<pre>` tag which holds the code, and call the following code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".close", function() {
    var formattedText= $(this).prev("textarea").val();
    $("pre").html(formattedText);
    $("textarea").hide();
});
```

Do note that to be safe here, you should give your textarea and `<pre>` tag IDs or classes so you can call them explicitly instead of just hoping there's only a single one of each type.

Comment: this will hide the whole text area box and the user cannot see what he has typed

Comment: They'll be able to see what they typed in the `<pre>` tag.  My understanding is that it is no longer an editable field, just the value they entered.

Comment: so you want add another markup "pre" in the html just to disable textarea?

Comment: Yes, this way you can remove the textarea but still display what the user entered.

Comment: don't you think it's little over head to add a new markup just to disable text area?

Comment: Given that he's no longer wanting it to function as a text area, why keep using one?  It's just another option.